# How to determine coefficients such that an integral is exact for all polynomials

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

If you are given an integral $\int_{0}^{3} f(x) dx= af(0)+bf(2)+cf(3)$

How would you find the constants, a,b,c such that the integral is exact for all polynomials f(x) for degree at most 2?

Answer (score 3):

Plug in
$f(x) = 1, x, x^2$
to get equations for
$a, b, c$.

If 
$f(x) = 1$,
then
$\int_0^3 f(x)dx
=\int_0^3 1 dx
=3
$,
so
$a+b+c = 3$.

If 
$f(x) = x$,
then
$\int_0^3 f(x)dx
=\int_0^3 x dx\frac{3^2}{2}
=\frac92
$,
so
$0+2b+3c = \frac92$.

If 
$f(x) = x^2$,
then
$\int_0^3 f(x)dx
=\int_0^3 x^2 dx
=\frac{3^3}{3}
=9
$,
so
$0a+4b+9c = 9$.

Solve these equations
to get
$a, b, c$.

Comment: Yea I did that. Came up with a = 9/14 , b= 18/7, c = -3/14.
I used matrix elimination.
Is that all that needed to show the integral is exact for all polynomials of degree 2?

Comment: Actually, that was way off. I came up with a= 3/4, b = 9/4, c = 0.

Comment: This is a much simpler approach than mine.  Of course, it comes to the same answer.  You are using the fact that the quadratic polynomials form a three dimensional vector space and the integral respects the structure of that space.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I would plug in the generic polynomial $f(x)=dx^2+ex+g$, do the integral and evaluate the terms like $f(0)$ on the right.  You will get an expression involving $d,e,g$ on both sides.  As you want this true for all quadratics, you can equate the terms in each variable, giving three equations in $a,b,c$.  Solve them and you are done.

Comment: I understand now you came up with the generic polynomial, up to term 2, but how far would we evaluate f(0)? That is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: $f(2)=4d+2e+g$  The others are similar

Comment: I don't even understand that, if you plug f(2) in the above equation you listed, answer is much larger.

Comment: $f(2)$ is just $f(x)$ with $2$ substituted for $x$.  The term $dx^2$ then is $d(2)^2=4d$.  That is for the right side.  For the left, you need to integrate $dx^2+ex+g$ over the range $0$ to $3$.